# Autohotkey - WinFocus not working

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I try to get Google Chrome focused by a Hotkey:

```
;Focus Chrome
^!l::
WinActivate,ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

Everytime i fire this Google Chrome get focused directly but then my IDE is getting focus immediately. No matter what window is focused while i press "**Ctrl+Alt+L**"

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I think you either have a global shortcut in your IDE, or you have another AutoHotkey key that activates your IDE.

Comment: Found out that i might need some "break" statement. If i switch the IDE-Focus shortcut it will do the opposite for the IDE.

Comment: is that really the whole script?

Comment: After what time focus gets back to IDE? If you manually(with your mouse, no script) make focus on Chrome, the focus gets back to IDE?

Comment: What a joke, if the accepted solution was truly the answer. Next time post your full script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added `return`, but it works for me:

```
^!l::
WinActivate,ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
return
```

Comment: That was the problem? Bummer! All the less understandable why questions like this get multiple upvotes.

Comment: @MCL for me was confusing question specially part about IDE... I tried his code and saw that it works, just opens additional window. So I tried with return and it seems it was escape...

Comment: I suspect what @JoeDF mentioned in the question's comments: Apparently, OP didn't post the whole script and some stuff was happening subsequently, probably another hotkey routine was triggered. It seems that in AHK, you have to teach the absolute basics over and over again. Such a shame that so many people don't even take a quick look at the docs, which are very enlightening and comprehensive.

Comment: @MCL agree `don't even take a quick look at the docs`. Even by searching you can find so many answers...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its easier to focus by executable name:

```
WinActivate,ahk_exe chrome.exe
```